# Prove irrational

Tags: proof-explanation

Prove that $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is irrational.

a.)Without assuming $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

b.)With assuming $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

For a.) would I just do a proof by contradiction.  Assuming that the entire expression is rational?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $${1+\sqrt{5}\over 2} = q\in \mathbb{Q}\;\;\; \Longrightarrow \;\;\;\sqrt{5} =2q-1$$

So if we already know that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational then we are finished since $2q-1$ is rational. Now suppose we don't know that. Then $2q-1 ={a\over b}$ for some relatively prime integers $a,b$. So $5 ={a^2\over b^2}$ and thus $a^2=5b^2$.

So $5|a^2$ so $5|a$ and we can write $a=5c$. Now we have $25c^2 = 5b^2$ and so $5|b^2$ and we have a contradiction since we assumed that $a,b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: how are you getting a=5c? what is c

Comment: oh never mind i see.

Comment: @JohnWatson yes, very interesting. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a) consider the polynomial $x^2-x-1=0$ then $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a root of the polynomial, now can you prove that there are no rational number $x$ such that $x^2-x-1=0$ ?

You can prove it by contradiction if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's for b) that a proof by contradiction would work very well:

If we assume that $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is rational, then $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{m}{n}$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.

Hence, $1 + \sqrt{5} = \frac{2m}{n}$, and therefore:

$$\sqrt{5} = \frac{2m}{n} -1 = \frac{2m-n}{n}$$

Since $m$ and $n$ are integers, $2m-n$ and $n$ are as well, which means that $\sqrt{5}$ is rational, which contradicts the assumption that it isn't.